# Can't save record to database => jaar: nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integer, rails-activerecord, database-migration, rails-migrations

I just wanted to add another field (jaar) to a form but it doesn't save to the database. I got 'nil' as a result.

`class AddJaarToStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :students, :jaar, :string
  end
end`

The field in my form:

```
<%= f.input :jaar, label: 'Leeftijd'%>
```

The provided value (jaar/leeftijd) is an integer, could that cause the problem of not saving to the database?

Kind regards,

Yves

Answer (score 0):

Did you whitelist jaar in your params list in the controller? If not, strong params will filter it out. You should take a look and see if jaar exists before the save occurs.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: Ok, I found the solution! I permitted these 'student' attributes in my application_controller. After I added :jaar it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, can you check to make sure you've added :jaar to your params list in your controller.

It could be not saving because the controller is not sending the :jaar column into the model.

Comment: My params look like this : 
params.require(:student).permit(availabilities_attributes: [ :id, :day, :available ])
The strange thing is: A student has :first_name, :last_name, :studie, etc. but I can't find them in the params and these attributes are saved in the DB! Even if I add :jaar to the params it doesn't work!

Comment: Thanks Brian, I checked my application_controller and I permitted :jaar! It works, thanks!